# Program refuses to continually consume memory

Tags: memory, clojure

I was trying [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101709/shortest-program-that-continuously-allocates-memory), which requires you to write a program that continually consumes memory.

I figured this would be easy, so I wrote up:

```
(reduce conj [] (range))
```

Which basically adds numbers from an infinite range into a vector; theoretically forever.

The problem is, this jumps up to 3/4GB of memory, then just stops. The CPU is still running hard, but it refuses to grow any larger.

I decided to steal an idea from a Java answer and override `finalize` to create more objects every time one is deallocated:

```
(defrecord A []
  Object
  (finalize [this] (mapv (fn [_] (A.)) (range 5)))) ; Create 5 more

(mapv (fn [_] (A.)) (range))
```

But this stops growing around the same point as well.

How is this not exploding? Especially since I'm using a strict `map`, it should be retaining everything in memory shouldn't it? As far as it "knows", I'll want it to print the entire list at some point, so it needs to hold onto everything. Plus, if it was deallocating at some point, shouldn't the overridden `finalize` method overcome this?

Can anyone explain what's going on here? I wrote this on my break, so I may be overlooking something, but I can't see what.
It was tested in Intellij/Cursive's REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JVM bascially spends the entire time garbage collecting. On my system the limit of the default heap size is ~8.7GB so depending what this gives you, your GC will be trying to stay below this even earlier:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize
```

You can increase this with `-Xmx` JVM option.

You program will actually continue running and keep adding things to your vector. I recommend  starting your JVM with the option `:XX:+PrintGCDetails` to see what's going on. After you get close to your heap limit the JVM will do Full GCs for seconds. Note, that [if the JVM spends too much time for the GC then it will throw and OOM error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded).

To see  that you're still allocating, just throw a `(when (zero? (rem x 1e5)) (println x))` in:

```
java -server -Xmx2g -XX:+PrintGCDetails -cp clojure-1.8.0.jar clojure.main -e '(mapv #(cond-> % (zero? (rem % 1e4)) println) (range))'
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I wonder how the Java answer worked then (if it did). I imagine they'd run into the same problem. They didn't mention changing their heap size. I wonder if that's necessary to mention in golf. Oh well, thanks for the explanation.